# .eof() substitute while using arrays

Tags: c++

So recently I've learned that using .eof can be considered a kind of big no no and I want to start moving away from it. One of the main substitutions I have seen is using

```
while(inFile >> num)
{

}
```

However, when I do this using arrays it only stores the first input and nothing else. Any tips?

Example:

```
while(inMovie >> title[x])
{
    inMovie >> income[x];
    x++;
}
```

Comment: Could you give us a minimal but complete example.  Completing this is a way I find obvious is working.

Comment: I'd do `for(; inMovie >> title[x] >> income[x]; x++) { }`, but your example looks like it'd work as it is. What makes you think it's only storing the first input?

Comment: Inside the loop body you should store `num` where you want to store it

Comment: @scohe001 In that code the user can cause a buffer overflow  .

Comment: @M.M how? And how can you be sure of that without knowing the type of `title[x]` or even whether or not the `>>` operator has been overloaded for that type?

Comment: @scohe001 neither of those things make a difference as to whether `title[x]` overflows or not.  Conceivably `title` might be an object of class type with overloaded `operator[]` that allows all possible integers as indices  but that would be very atypical behaviour. In the more usual case that `title` is an array or a vector or any other random access standard container, eventually `title[x]` will access out of bounds

Comment: Unrelated: Rather than multiple arrays each tracking one variable, consider aggregating your variables into a structure and having a single array of that structure.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want to be doing is:

```
while ((inMovie >> title[x]) && (inMovie >> income[x]))
{
   x++;
}
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
while (inMovie >> title[x] >> income[x])
{
   x++;
}
```

This way, both input operations have to "succeed" in order for you to continue.

That being said, there is nothing inherently broken with your attempt, and there is no reason for it to "only store the first input" as long as the input is correct.

Check your input.

I'm also concerned that you may not be using arrays properly. Does your array have enough space for all these elements? Or are you expecting `title` and `income` to expand automatically? Because they won't do that. In that case, your program has undefined behaviour (which may produce all sorts of weird results!) and you should consider using a vector instead.

Comment: This allows a buffer overflow by the input

Comment: @M.M. In what sense?

Comment: The intput could keep supplying values until `title[x]` accesses out of bounds  (a program should not allow user input to lead to undefined behaviour)

Comment: @M.M Did I not say that in the answer?